# Toggleclass not working?

Tags: jquery, html, css, class, toggle

I am trying to make the 'timelineTile' div open and close and also close if another is opened and also close when the background is clicked, i have managed to get it to close if another is clicked and the background but i can't get the div to close if the div itself is clicked... here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y97g74vc/4/)

my code;

```js
$(function () {
    $('.timelineTile').click(function (evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        $('.selected').children().removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    });


    $(document).click(function () {
        $('.timelineTile').removeClass('clicked');
    });
});
```

```css
.timelineTile.clicked{
    background:red;
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    -webkit-transition:height 1s, left 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
    transition:height 1s, left 1s, transform 1s;
}

.selected {
    -webkit-transition:height 1s, left 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
    transition:height 1s, left 1s, transform 1s; 
}


.timelineTile {
   background:black; 
    color:white;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    -webkit-transition:height 1s, left 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
    transition:height 1s, left 1s, transform 1s;
}

.timelineTilehold {
    background:pink;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="timelineTilehold">
    
    <li class="selected"><div class="timelineTile">hello
    </div></li>

<li class="selected"><div class="timelineTile">hello
    </div></li>

<li class="selected"><div class="timelineTile">hello
    </div></li></ul>
```

Comment: You will need to return false in your document click method. Otherwise the bubbling of the event will cause the clicked class to toggle again

Comment: if I remove that it then stops the 'close if another is clicked'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.not()` so you don't remove the class on clicked element

```
$('.timelineTile').click(function (evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    $('.selected').children().not(this).removeClass('clicked');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y97g74vc/5/)

Comment: Not a requirement, but take a look at the new [Stack Snippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?cb=1), so you don't need to link to jsfiddler.

Comment: @gunr2171 Yeah i know about it but i don't like the format the stack snippets creates.